# Using a filter with the lookupFSC component

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm using the lookupFSC component in a screen flow.  I'm looking up contacts and would like to filter the available contacts based on the value of a rollup summary field.  I can't seem to set the filter correctly.  Can anyone help?

Comment: That component looks like it has a few different settings that contribute to how it filters.  Are you able to share some additional detail?  Maybe include a screenshot of your current config so we get an idea of what you're trying to do?